# Add meta tag with image and title to Angular 6 project

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to add an image and title when sending the url of one page in my project, and I'm looking the best way on how to do it. This is what I tried:

```
createMetaTag() {
    const meta = document.createElement('meta');
    meta.setAttribute('property', 'og:image');
    meta.content = '' + this.activeCampaignModel.thumbnail;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);


    const meta2 = document.createElement('meta');
    meta2.setAttribute('property', 'og:title');
    meta2.content = 'Results for: ' + this.activeCampaignModel.name;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta2);

}
```

Now when I share the link nothing happens, I send the link on skype for example, the page has meta tags with title and image, but nothing happens... In skype, no image is shown and no title. This is how the meta tags look like:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://somethingsomething.png">
<meta property="og:title" content="Results for: Test Graph v3">
```

**EDIT**

I implemented the code with setAttribute, but still nothing happening.

**EDIT 2**

I tried adding all the meta tags, with name and property attributes, not working as well. This is the code for the rest of tags (all get created in the head section):

```
    const meta3 = document.createElement('meta');
    meta3.setAttribute('name', 'og:type');
    meta3.content = 'website';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta3);

    const meta4 = document.createElement('meta');
    meta4.setAttribute('name', 'og:url');
    meta4.content = '' + environment.resultsUrl;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta4);

    const meta5 = document.createElement('meta');
    meta5.setAttribute('name', 'og:description');
    meta5.content = ' ';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta5);
```

**Edit 3**

Found the problem, but not the solution. Meta tags are generated later, when the component loads, when you look at the page source it looks completely different and meta tags are not there, just `app-root` with no scripts/links, as you can see in the image:

[image]

Comment: Can you try replacing `property` keyword with `name` and check again?

Answer (score 2):

As per my knowledge,

Meta tag only accepts two properties `name` and `content`.

```
<meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, XML, XHTML, JavaScript">
```

You can try replacing property keyword with name and check again.

```
<script type='text/javascript' data-cfasync='false'>
  createMetaTag() {
      var link=document.createElement('meta');
      link.name="og:image";
      link.content = '' + this.activeCampaignModel.thumbnail;
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
 }
</script>
```

[Reference Link](https://support.shareaholic.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005177166-Adding-Meta-Tags-using-JavaScript)

Comment: I am still not getting the thumbnail while sharing the url, meta tag looks fine and image url is in the content, but when sharing, nothing happens

Answer (score 2):

The `property` is a proprietary attribute used by Facebook, so it's not a standard DOM attribute and therefore not in the Typescript typings definitions for the DOM that you are using. You can use `setAttribute` to set an arbitrary attribute on an HTML element.

```
createMetaTag() {
    const meta = document.createElement('meta');
    meta.setAttribute('property','og:image'); //this line is the issue
    meta.content = '' + this.activeCampaignModel.thumbnail;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
}
```

Comment: Now the meta tag doesn't show property attribute, just the content, but still not showing the thumbnail when sending someone url :/

Comment: maybe you need to use meta.setAttribute('property','og:image') instead

Comment: I updated the code, and the question, it creates the proper meta tags but doesn't work :/